# What's the most optimal team for Weekend Meowth?

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

I'm interested in making the most amount of coins possible from the Weekend Meowth event each week. Which team loadout will help me secure as many coins as possible from the Weekend Meowth event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mega Evolution:**
You need a Pokemon which Ability ensures you a good chance of 3+ combo, because that's what triggers the Coins disruption. So, I suggest *MegaGengar*, *MegaBanette*, *MegaRayquaza*, *MegaMewtwoY* or *MegaSalamence*, because they erase several tiles of the same Pokemon in the puzzle area.

**Useful Abilities:**
The rest of your team should have abilities that can help you get combos.
For example **Quirky** and **Quirky+**, which occasionally erase one/two extra matching Pokémon elsewhere (respectively).
These are *Quirky*+ Pokemon: *Cherrim*, *Xerneas*, *Furfrou*, *Malamar*, *Gogoat*, *Gothitelle*, *Weezing* and *Lumineon*.

If you prefer *MegaRayquaza* or *MegaMewtwoY* (and you don't want to spend 2000 coins for a *MegaStart*) it's useful to bring, respectively, *Zygarde-10%* or *Unown-!* because their Ability **MegaBoost+** adds a good amount to the Mega Gauge.

*MegaSalamence* strategy lacks a MegaBoost+ user, but a *Skill Swapped* Salamence own MegaBoost itself.

It's worth noting that, if you choose *Banette* as your Mega, you need at least a *Ghost*-type Pokemon to exploit its ability. Also, *Haunter* and *Yamask* own *Quirky*.
*Mewtwo* erases only *Psychic*-type Pokemon.
*Salamence* erases only *Flying*-type Pokemon.
*Rayquaza* erases only non-*Dragon*-type tiles.

Another strategy is to leave the 4th slot empty, in that case it will be replaced by Pidgey as a non-support Pokemon. The benefit is that *Pidgey* tiles can now be erased with **Eject** (or better versions) to help combos.
For example *SS Manaphy* owns **Eject++**, and *Lugia* (useful for *MegaSalamence* strategy) owns **Eject+**.

**Items:**

- **Moves+5** is a MUST. You need those extra moves to make money, and 800 Coins will be worth it.
- **MegaStart** is useful if you choose *MegaBanette* or *MegaRayquaza*, because they evolve very slowly (unless they are full candied or you prefer the *MegaBoost* team strategy). However *MegaGengar*'s evolution is really fast. In the latter case you don't need it.

---

#### <s>Complexity-1 Exploit:</s>

<sup>(This trick was probably a bug that only worked for *Weekend Meowth* of 17th April, so it **doesn't work anymore**.)</sup>

That day you could buy more items unlike before. For example,  **Complexity-1**.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**:
If you simply add it to the strategy I've explained above, ***Complexity-1* will just remove the Coins**, which are seen like the "fifth" Support of your team.

So, how can you correctly exploit it? In this way:

[image]

You have to leave the last slot empty, in this way Coins will get the fourth Support slot and as "fifth" you'll now have a random Pokemon, that will be removed by *Complexity-1*.

You can choose whatever 3-Pokemon team you prefer, following the original strategy, and you will now get a huge quantity of combos and Coins disruptions.

And you should end with something like this:

[image]

This starting set of *+5 moves* (800), *MegaStart* (2000) and *Complexity-1* (9000) will cost you 11800 Coins, but it is totally worth the expense, as you can see.